# Jupyter matplotlib plot does not respond to setting xlim or to modifications to x-axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am new to Juptyer and to matplotlib, so I'm struggling to adjust the x-axis range on my plots.

Here's my code:

```
plt.figure(1)

l_dt = dt[dt['datatype'] == 2.0]
if len(l_dt['time'].values) > 1:
    plt.subplot(223)
    plt.scatter(l_dt['time'].values, l_dt['measurementvalue'].values)
    plt.yscale('linear')
    plt.title('Carbs (g)')
    plt.grid(True)

l_dt = dt[dt['datatype'] == 3.0]
if len(l_dt['time'].values) > 1:
    plt.subplot(224)
    plt.scatter(l_dt['time'].values, l_dt['measurementvalue'].values)
    plt.yscale('linear')
    plt.title('Activity (mins)')
    plt.grid(True)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlim(min(dt['time']), max(dt['time']))
plt.show()

print(min(dt['time']))
print(min(dt['time']))
```

Here's my output:

[image: output]

As you can see, even though my log statement shows a min date in April 25 and a max date of May 9, I am seeing my axes in one case go all the way back to March despite this line in the code:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.xlim(min(dt['time']), max(dt['time']))
```

Here's what I've tried

- I tried moving the `xlim` line to before plotting, but this has not changed the behavior.
- I tried moving the 'xlim' line just before each `plt.subplot`

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: post some of your data to create a working example

Comment: `plt.xlim(min(dt['time']), max(dt['time']))` is only going to operate on the current Axes, not all of them, btw. This is exactly why the `pyplot` & `pylab` interfaces should be avoided in favor of the object-oriented interface.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (which I do since there's no data to play with), you understandably expect `plt.xlim` to set the limits for all of the axes.

However, the `pyplot` interface only operates on the current axes as tracked by the matplotlib state machine. This can get tricky as you and the state machine's might disagree on which Axes is The Current Axes.

I would modify you example use the object-oriented interface:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 8), sharex=True)

l_dt = dt[dt['datatype'] == 2.0]
if len(l_dt['time'].values) > 1:
    axes[1, 0].scatter('time', 'measurementvalue', data=l_dt)
    axes[1, 0].set_yscale('linear')
    axes[1, 0].set_title('Carbs (g)')
    axes[1, 0].grid(True)

l_dt = dt[dt['datatype'] == 3.0]
if len(l_dt['time'].values) > 1:
    axes[1, 1].scatter('time', 'measurementvalue', data=l_dt)
    axes[1, 1].set_yscale('linear')
    axes[1, 1].set_title('Activity (mins)')
    axes[1, 1].grid(True)

fig.tight_layout()
pyplot.show()
```

Using `sharex=True` when you create the figure will keep the x-axes synced across all of the subplots.